# Google Web Client with Oauth2 suddenly stops working

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, django-allauth, google-signin, google-api-python-client

I'm creating a Social Platform using Google Login. The App works fine until next day that stop recieving the callback URI correctly when I try again to login with google.

Everytime I get the error I create a new Web Client and works just fine until the next day that I get a `401 Error`, then change the URI callback to `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`. It starts working just fine until the next day that I get the `400 Error`.[image]

Any idea what is causing this change that the system stops working after 1 day? It start asking for `127.0.0.1` but even if I put that it gets the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI in Google deveoper console needs to exactly match the one your code is sending from.

you are sending from http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/  and its not in your list of approved redirect uris.

Remember the full path needs to match with the port.